# Change behavior of Flask-based API depending on whether the client is streaming the response or not

Tags: python, flask

I have an API made in Python/Flask, which returns data as a list of dictionaries/JSONs. It can return a significant amount of data, so I would like it to be able to stream data to a client. I already have the necessary code to generate the stream of data, I just need to figure out how to provide this stream to clients.

I would like it to be up to the client to decide if they want the result to be streamed or not, ie if they don't stream the response they get a valid list of dicts directly, but if they stream the response they'll get each dict separated by newlines.

So far, my implementation is old and based on this [blog post](https://blog.al4.co.nz/2016/01/streaming-json-with-flask/), and as pointed out in the blog post update, it isn't very good: requesting data **without streaming** results in a proper list of dicts, but **streaming it** results in a bunch of barely usable chunks of dicts.

I have tried the following new approach (I have somewhat simplified the exemple, here `data_generator` provides the data iteratively)

```py
@app.route("/get_data", methods=["GET"])
def get_data(**kwargs):
    def stream_response():
        rows = data_generator
        for row in rows:
            yield json.dumps(row) + "\n"
    return Response(stream_response(), mimetype="application/json")
```

It works and streams the data dict by dict, but the whole response (when not streamed) is not a valid, decodable JSON.

Is there a standard way to detect server-side if a client is asking for a stream of data or the whole result, so I can return valid data in both cases ? I have thought of adding an argument or header to the API so that client can specify what they need but I would like a more "universal" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it sounds like your streaming data is using the [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format. There's no native Flask support for that, I'm afraid, but knowing the name might help find more resources.

> Is there a standard way to detect server-side if a client is asking for a stream of data

I don't think there is a reliable way of detecting streaming clients. *Especially* before you even send the first byte of the response body.

My suggestion is to make the client signal which one it wants. And there's already a perfectly fine header for that, [`Accept: mimetype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept).

```
@app.route("/get_data", methods=["GET"])
def get_data(**kwargs):
    # Not an official mimetype, but already in use by AWS.
    if request.accept_mimetypes['application/jsonlines']:
        def stream_response():
            rows = data_generator
            for row in rows:
                yield json.dumps(row) + "\n"
        return Response(stream_response(), mimetype="application/jsonlines")
    else:
        # Send all data at once.
        return jsonify(list(data_generator))
```

Then on the streaming client side, you must set the Accept header, like so (Javascript example):

```js
fetch('/get_data', {headers: {'Accept': 'application/jsonlines'}})
```